# Burned out bulb might have drained my battery

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, bulbs

I was cleaning the car last night and noticed the overhead bulb for the back seat is burned out. It was on position 'Door' (i.e. lights when the door is open). I've switched it off and on a couple of times and clearly remember I left it 'On'. Next morning my battery (5 year old) was dead. Jump started the car, drove it around, battery recharged.

To my question - is it possible that a a dead bulb consumes so much electricity, it drains an entire battery (provided, I've drained a little beforehand with a couple of engine starts and using the power seats without engine running).

The car is Honda Accord 2008 V6.

Edit: I think I found which bulb it is: https://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~bulb~04110-swa-305.html

> 04110-SWA-305

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not possible. A dead bulb is just that ... *dead*. There is no continuity to light the bulb, therefore there's no continuity to drain the battery. Instead, I'd look at the battery itself. It's 5 years old, which is the (arguable) normal lifespan of a good battery. I'd bet if you had it load tested, you'll find it needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I thought too. But this [link](https://www.quora.com/If-a-lightbulb-is-burnt-out-does-it-still-consume-electricity-when-you-turn-the-light-switch-on) and the "Good" battery result test made me second guess.

Comment: I see what the link is stating about LED's and the like, but your bulb is an incandescent bulb ... once dead ... it's dead.

Comment: Also, i don't put much stock in "Quora" answers ... ;-)